# Is there a way to change src of few images at once in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I did some research and there are many questions about changing src of an image in JavaScript. However I want to change src of three images when clicking on button at once.

HTML:

```
<ul class="items-list">
 <li><a href="#!" onclick="changeImage()">Shoes</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">T-shirts</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="item"><img src="img/t-shirt.jpg" alt="" class="items" id="imgChange">
<div class="item"><img src="img/hoodie.jpg" alt="" class="items">
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeImage(){
let change = document.querySelector('#imgChange').src="img/shoe.png";}
```

So this code works perfectly but it changes only one image. I want to change 2 or more images at one click. I've tried to get element by class but it still changes only first image. So in this case I want to change image in the second div too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector` selects only the first element and `document.querySelector('#imgChange')` will select  first element which have the `id`.Use `document.querySelectorAll('img')` it will select all the `img` tag. Use `forEach` to iterate the loop and change the `src`

```js
function changeImage() {
  let change = document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(item) {
    item.src = "img/shoe.png";
  })
}
```

```html
<ul class="items-list">
  <li><a href="#!" onclick="changeImage()">Shoes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">T-shirts</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="item">
  <img src="img/t-shirt.jpg" alt="" class="items" id="imgChange">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="img/hoodie.jpg" alt="" class="items">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, such an easy solution.

Comment: How would you implement this solution in changing one `img` tag?

Comment: How to decide which img tag need to be changed ?

Answer (score 0):

querySelector() method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

Try 
`var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names)`
to get all elements with the same class name. Or, try `var element = document.getElementById(id)` for finer selection.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use getElementsByClassName but it didn't work. Thankfully solution by brk works for me. Thanks.